# Does garbage collector reclaim value type memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, garbage-collection

When I declare `int a = 0;` as it is value type it gets memory from stack so when this variable goes out of scope does garbage collector reclaim this memory?

Comment: Surely it is marked for garbage collection, but not necessarily actually garbage collected at that point?

Comment: You should read [The Truth About Value Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: The first error here is that you assume that the int a = 0; is collected by CG - maybe your question is for any data that go to CG... or what is happens with the int value inside a function ?

Answer (score 16):

> When I declare int a = 0; as it is value type it gets memory from stack

That is correct -- assuming that the local variable is short lived -- but the logic is wrong.  When you declare *any short lived local* it gets its memory from the *short term memory pool*, which *might* be the stack, or it might be a register. It gets its memory from the short term pool regardless of whether it is a *value type* or a *reference to an object of reference type*. Either way, the memory is allocated on the short term pool if the variable is short-lived.

That is, when you have a short-lived local

```
object x = null;
```

the storage for *the reference to the object* is allocated on the short term pool. The storage for the referred-to object, if there is one, is allocated on the long-term pool, the heap. In this case the reference is null.

> when this variable goes out of scope does garbage collector reclaim this memory?

No. The *garbage collector* only collects memory that was allocated on the long term pool, also known as the heap.

The garbage collector of course must know about the short term pool; if there are *references* in the short term pool then those references might be to things that are alive. But the garbage collector can safely ignore all value types *that do not contains references* that are in the short-term pool.

**Why are you asking the question? I suspect that there is a deeper question here that is being hidden.**

Comment: Eric , exactly what I was looking for , still - (related), Reading your article  , you said that --looking at the stack , moving the pointer 1 step up - is extremely easy and cheap - hence we use that _whenever we can_. But what about those value type which **DO** have reference to long live objects ? isn't that impact  the performance of the _sweep_ part ? I mean how does a `pop()`  is done if It can't `pop()` it - because it's referencing a long living object in the heap ...

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You've got it backwards. You said that you can't pop the stack because the stack refers to something alive, but it's the opposite. The thing is alive *because it is referred to by the stack*. When the stack is popped, there has to be *something else* that is keeping the referred-to object alive; if there isn't, then it's dead.